# Dealing with Unicode in python xml elements

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing, hebrew

I have an xml file with hebrew content for some of it attributes.
I do in python:

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
tree = ET.parse(fInput,parser)
root = tree.getroot()
```

and from there I can loop over len(root) objects, and start dealing with it with the .text property.
However, for hebrew texts I get, for example,

```
>>> elem[0].text
u'\u05ea\u05d5\u05dd'
```

I wish to convert this xml into SQL insert functions, in order to insert it to my database.
How can I read those properties correctly, in order to actually having hebrew string in my hand?

Comment: Unicode character 05ea is [Hebrew letter Tav](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x05EA/index.html), so that looks correct.

Comment: Ok I think I found my problem. I didnt write it correctly to a file. Can I simply use s.encode('UTF-8') over all text's I extract from elements? (wether they're hebrew texts or not)

Comment: You specify the encoding for the file, and yes, you can write all text to one file. However, you may have to be aware of direction problems (right-to-left vs left-to-right text).  The program you use to view the file must be capable of handling this or you'll get strange results.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode character 05ea is [Hebrew letter Tav](http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x05EA/index.html), or ת so that looks like you are correctly reading UTF-8 encoded Hebrew text.  The complete string is **"תום"**. All you have to do is ensure that the database field you write this into is configured as either UTF-8 or UTF-16.